# assembleRelease in an android library Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to build a library with this microsoft msal library using :

> ```
> implementation 'com.microsoft.identity.client:msal:1.4.0'
> ```

when I remove it the assemblerelease works fine , but when I use it it crashes on

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

I tried looking around but didn't find any indication to something similar ,

I'm using compileSdkVersion 27 (Pre request) if it matters

Any help with this crash ?

** EDIT - this is the real crash log :

```
Printing classes to [C:\dev\git\\MyProj\build\outputs\mapping\release\dump.txt]...
C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.2.aar\1064ae02a9be19daa8f91791fbe2485f\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

C:\dev\git\\MyProj\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.2.aar\1064ae02a9be19daa8f91791fbe2485f\res\values\values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.2.aar\1064ae02a9be19daa8f91791fbe2485f\res\values\values.xml:1304:5-69: AAPT: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

C:\dev\git\\MyProj\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
C:\dev\git\\MyProj\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
   C:\dev\git\\MyProj\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:762: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\dev\git\MyProj\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:762: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: The actual build error should be somewhere in the earlier build output.

Comment: @laalto added it , thanks !